# arm/disarm home security system arduino keypad lcd

Tags: arduino, lcd, keypad

So I run into a problem when I am trying to disarm the system. When I upload the code to the arduino it asks me to enter a pin and then it activates the system right away. But then when I try to deactivate the system it takes the pin and just clears the screen and execute the mainScreen function that i have set.

The code is provided below:

```
#include "Keypad.h"
#include "LiquidCrystal.h"
#include "Password.h"
LiquidCrystal lcd(0,1,10,11,12,13);
char newPasswordString; //hold the new password
char newPassword[4]; //charater string of newPasswordString

//initialize password to 1234
//you can use password.set(newPassword) to overwrite it
Password password = Password("1234");

byte maxPasswordLength = 4; 
byte currentPasswordLength = 4;
// keypad type definition
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{'1','2','3','A'},
{'4','5','6','B'},
{'7','8','9','C'},
{'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9,8,7,6}; //Rows 0 to 3
byte colPins[COLS]= {5,4,3,2}; //Columns 0 to 3
int count=0;     
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );
void setup()
{    
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  mainScreen();
}
void loop(){
   char key = keypad.getKey();
   if (key != NO_KEY){
      delay(60); 
      switch (key){
      case 'A': activate(); break; 
      case 'B': break; 
      case 'C': break; 
      case 'D': deactivate(); break; 
      case '#':  break;
      case '*': break;
      default: processNumberKey(key);
      }
   }
}
void processNumberKey(char key) {
   lcd.print(key);
   currentPasswordLength++;
   password.append(key);
   if(password.evaluate()){
    activate();
   }
}    
void activate() {
   if (password.evaluate()){
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Activated.");
      delay(1000);
      mainScreen();
   } else {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Wrong Password!");
            mainScreen();    
   } 
}
void deactivate(){
    if (password.evaluate()){
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Deactivated.");
      delay(1000);
   } else {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Wrong Password!");
      mainScreen();
   } 
}
void mainScreen(){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Enter Pin:");
  keypad.getKey();
  }
```

Comment: no need for a pin, just press D to deactivate...

Comment: How to I get it to accept the pin

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [Arduino keypad 4x4 to LCD activate/deactivate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40966687/5271927) you have to keep current state and you have to **CLEAR** the `password` and `currenPasswordLength`. See the WORKING example in the answer.

It won't help that you set `byte currenPasswordLength = 4`. If you press first key, it will be incremented to 5, next key increments it to the 6 and so on.

You'll get 4 again after the 256 key-presses!!!!!!! And as you don't clear previously checked password, you'll get "wrong password" result (and eventually stack overflow).